# Sharepoint time is one hour ahead of actual time

Tags: wss-3.0

I use WSS 3.0

Its shows time which is one hour ahead of the actual time.!!

How to solve it?

pls help!

-saumil

Comment: Time on the server? Or the time you see elsewhere in the system like Date Created, Last Updated etc?

Comment: Time Elsewhere NOT Server Time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SharePoint will use the server time. So if you are not in the same time zone as the server this is the expected behavior.

You can set up your own time zone for your site:

Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Administration > Regional Settings

Comment: I checked the settings .... Its perfect!! But still time shown for tasks, announcements etc is still 1 hour ahead,!